# How do i can resolve this promblem?

Tags: t-sql

I have an table include 1 column ID and 12 columns month (Month01 to Month12). If i have an parameter @month=9, how can i compare to get column Month01 to Month09 without Month10, Month11, Month12. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

you may try this out also :)

```
DECLARE @month int  = 9
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(100) =''
DECLARE @pos int = 1
WHILE(@pos <= @month)
BEGIN
   SET @Sql = @Sql + (',month' + right('00'+ rtrim(@pos), 2)) 
   SET @pos = @pos + 1
END
SET @Sql= 'SELECT ID ' +@Sql + ' FROM table'
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @month int
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(128)

SET @month = 9;
SET @tableName = 'months' -- YOUR TABLE's NAME

DECLARE @query nvarchar(2048)
SET @query = 
'SELECT id, ' + STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + name 
   FROM sys.columns WHERE name LIKE'Month%' 
   AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)
   AND CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(name, 2)) <= @month 
   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') 
   + ' FROM ' + @tableName;  

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you filter `sys.columns` on `object_id`? What if another table has a column named `MonthValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Simo's answer is more elegant, but below is an alternative "basic" way to do this:

```sql
DECLARE @month INT
SET @month = 9

IF @Month = 1
BEGIN
  SELECT Id, Month01
    FROM MonthlyData
END

IF @Month = 2
BEGIN
  SELECT Id, Month01, Month02
    FROM MonthlyData
END

-- Repeat for months 3-9

IF @Month = 9
BEGIN
  SELECT Id, Month01, Month02, Month03, Month04,
         Month05, Month06, Month07, Month08, Month09
    FROM MonthlyData
END

-- Repeat for months 10-12
```

See my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3d7b/3/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @str varchar(1000)

SELECT @str= coalesce(@str + ', ', '') + a.name 
FROM (
      Select name from sys.columns
      where object_id = OBJECT_ID('table_months')
      and isnumeric(right(name,2))= 1 and name like 'month%'
      and cast(right(name,2) as int) < '03') a
```

-- Instead of '03' you use a variable and assign required moths number

```
declare @sql  nvarchar(100)

set @sql = 'select ID, '+ @str+' from table_months'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```